# Can Webmin run as sudoer instead of root?

Tags: sudo, webmin

Have someone some experience with using xinetd with a user which is not root, but instead a sudoer?

The operations that are required to be done do not always requires admin priviledges : ex retrieving a system cpu usage does not need to be root at all.  For security purpose, i would like to restrict the operations that can be handled with the Webmin interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webmin is usually run as the Apache user, not as root. `xinetd`, on the other hand, which can be controlled with Webmin, must be run as root because it binds to privileged ports (< 1024), which only root can do.